# How do i access the "ID" in MS SQL Server Mangement Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: SQL Management Studio Picture]

I need to access the red marked "id". There is no id in the query. How do i access it ?
I want to access it via a `Select` statement, of course.

Comment: You don't. Rows have no "ID". That's just a grid row number.

Comment: That's not an id. Its just the row number.

Comment: you can't. You can generate your own using `row_number()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generate a number to display on a grid? Perhaps your grid control *already* supports this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot exactly "access" it.  You can calculate it using `row_number()`.

Tables represent *unordered* sets.  So there is no inherent ordering.  I cannot tell if any columns specify the ordering.  But you can do the calculation as:

```
select row_number() over (order by uid) as id, t.*
from t;
```

If you want insertion order for the table, you should add an `identity()` column to capture the insertion order.  To be accurate, you should recreate the table.

You don't have to specify a column if you use:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id, t.*
from t;
```

In this case, the result is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Beat me to it. Is there some gimmick to avoid using an actual field in order by?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yes, use `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` but the order will be random.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not "random" - just "undefined".